# Android Non UI Thread can update UI in while loop?

Tags: java, android

I don't know why non UI thread can update the text view in while loop like this:

```
Runnable timeCount = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mTextView.setText(i++ + "");
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(timeCount);
        thread.start();
```

has been called after Activity Resume.
Please help to explain about this!

Answer (score 0):

the ViewRoot will call the checkThread() to check if it's the main thread ，if your thread be called just before the method of checkThread() .it will not to throw the error。

Comment: Give more info , source code etc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in documentation(https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads.html#references) Android UI classes are not thread safe.

If you try to update View objects from any other thread than the one created it you may face anomaly. Sometimes it may seem to work however there are no guarantees.